# Python: Creating an empty file object

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I am attempting to make a logging module for Python that does not work because it fails on creation of the file object.

debug.py:

```
import os
import datetime
import globals

global fil
fil = None

def init(fname):
     fil = open(fname, 'w+')
     fil.write("# PyIDE Log for" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

def log(strn):
    currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()

    fil.write(str(currentTime) + ' ' + str(os.getpid()) + ' ' + strn)
    print str(currentTime) + ' ' + str(os.getpid()) + ' ' + strn

def halt():
    fil.close()
```

fil will not work as `None` as I get an `AttributeError`. I also tried creating a dummy object:

```
fil = open("dummy.tmp","w+")
```

but the `dummy.tmp` file is written to instead, even though `init()` is called before `log()` is. Obviously you cannot open a new file over an already opened file. I attempted to close `fil` before `init()`, but Python said it could not perform `write()` on a closed file.

This is the code that is accessing `debug.py`

```
if os.path.exists(temp):
         os.rename(temp, os.path.join("logs","archived","log-" + str(os.path.getctime(temp)) + ".txt"))
         debug.init(globals.logPath)
         debug.log("Logger initialized!")
```

I would like to have logging in my program and I cannot find a workaround for this.

Comment: out of curiosity, why arent you encompassign this in a class? Im pretty sure you would avoid this issue if you did this in a class

Comment: @septi this won't work because I have a log archiving system set up. See the last code snippet. The file accesses conflict. If I open the file with `debug.py` before `init()` then I will not be able to wite because it is already used by a process.

Comment: @TehTris No, completely self taught.

Comment: Oh, lol, nice. you are going to like my answer then.

Comment: he is attempting to MAKE a logger module, not use an existing one BTW

Comment: @GalenNare I don't get it. You have probably no idea how powerful the `logging` module is?

Comment: @septi I looked at it and I still prefer not to use it. It still gets in the way of log archiving.

Comment: Do what you need to do, but I'm pretty sure that you waste your time reimplementing stuff that is already there (and tested). ; )

Comment: its also possible hes just trying to learn how to do something on his own? its always good practice to implement something that already exists on your own.

Comment: @TehTris is right. I have only been using Python for a couple months. I'm not exactly what you would consider professional.

Comment: It's always a good practice to learn some basic modules which are used in nearly every single project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't assign to the global `fil`:

```
def init(fname):
    fil = open(fname, 'w+')
```

This creates a new local variable called `fil`.

If you want to assign to the global variable `fil` you need to bring it into the local scope:

```
def init(fname):
    global fil
    fil = open(fname, 'w+')
```

Comment: Thank you. I had learned that `global` could only be used outside of functions. I learned wrong.

Comment: And now learn to forget `global` at all and try to not use it ever again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to MAKE your own logging module, then you may want to turn what you already have  into a class, so you can import it as a module.

```
#LoggerThingie.py
import os
import datetime



class LoggerThingie(object):
    def __init__(self,fname):
         self.fil = open(fname, 'w+')
         self.fil.write("# PyIDE Log for" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

    def log(self,strn):
        currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.fil.write(str(currentTime) + ' ' + str(os.getpid()) + ' ' + strn)
        print str(currentTime) + ' ' + str(os.getpid()) + ' ' + strn

    def halt(self):
        self.fil.close()
```

If you did this as a class, you would not have to keep track of globals in the first place (which is generally understood as bad practice in the world of programming: [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil) )

Since it is now a module on its own, when you want to use it in another python program you would do this:

```
from LoggerThingie import LoggerThingie
#because module filename is LoggerThingie.py and ClassName is LoggerThingie
```

and then use it wherever you want, for example:

```
x = LoggerThingie('filename.txt') #create LoggerThingie object named x
```

and every-time you want to insert logs into it:

```
x.log('log this to the file')
```

and when you are finally done:

```
x.halt() # when ur done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to start with an empty file you could use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to keep the messages in memory and write them to disk at the end but be careful, if something happened and you didn't wrote the messages they will be lost.

Comment: Please look at the comments on the question.